# How can I reshape my data with two j variables one of which is a string?

Tags: stata

My data looks a bit like this. The first row is variable names and the rest are my values. `year` describes the year of an election, `nutsid` is a sort of regional identifier and `nutsname` is the name of the region. Now I want to focus on the next three: `spo`, `ovp`, and `fpo` are the names of parties in the election. I want to combine them all under one variable called `party` and keep the long format I have now.

```
   | year     nutsid    nutsname        spo      ovp      fpo|
1. | 2008     AT11      Burgenland    73565    52531    29812|
2. | 1990     AT11      Burgenland    88547    62675    19508|
3. etc
```

What I have tried so far is to use the `reshape` command to reshape it all into wide format first and then renaming them something like `p_spo`, `p_ovp`, `p_fpo` using

```
reshape long p_, i(nutsid) j(year party) string
```

I can't say that this was a smart idea or that it worked because it just gives me a new id called `year` with the value `"party"` written under it over and over again.

But I was wondering if there was another command I should be using to get from what I have to:

```
   | year     nutsid    nutsname      party  votes|
1. | 2008     AT11      Burgenland    spo    73565|    
2. | 2008     AT11      Burgenland    ovp    52531|    
3. | 2008     AT11      Burgenland    fpo    29812|    
4. | 1990     AT11      Burgenland    spo    88547|
5. | 1990     AT11      Burgenland    ovp    62675|
6. | 1990     AT11      Burgenland    fpo    19508|
7. etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor details here are confused or unclear:

1. In Stata variable names are not to be considered or described as the "first row" of the data, although they will appear as headers in (e.g.) the Data Editor. Stata is not a spreadsheet application.
2. The `reshape` command you mention requires that `spo ovp fpo` be `rename`d to 
   `p_spo p_ovp p_fpo` **before** the `reshape`; this renaming does not follow the `reshape`.
3. Exactly what you did is unclear as you give only part of your syntax.

That said, what you want is a simple `reshape`:

```
clear 
input year str4 nutsid str10  nutsname        spo      ovp      fpo
2008     AT11      Burgenland    73565    52531    29812
1990     AT11      Burgenland    88547    62675    19508
end 
rename (spo ovp fpo) (votes=) 
reshape long votes, i(nutsid year) j(party) string 
list, sepby(nutsid year) 

     +--------------------------------------------+
     | nutsid   year   party     nutsname   votes |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |   AT11   1990     fpo   Burgenland   19508 |
  2. |   AT11   1990     ovp   Burgenland   62675 |
  3. |   AT11   1990     spo   Burgenland   88547 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  4. |   AT11   2008     fpo   Burgenland   29812 |
  5. |   AT11   2008     ovp   Burgenland   52531 |
  6. |   AT11   2008     spo   Burgenland   73565 |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

In this view of the data, you have two so-called `i` variables and one `j` variable.

Note the use here of `input` code to give a data example that will run without the engineering that your example requires. You can install the command `dataex` using `ssc inst dataex` to make this easy on yourself too.